# Unexpected voltages on home-made OR gate

Tags: transistors, logic-gates, npn

I've created some home-made gates using discreet components onto strip board.
So far I have an OR gates, an AND gate and 4 NOR gates.
Logically they all work as expected but on only one of my 4 NOR gates I am getting some weird unexpected voltages on the 2 inputs and the voltage on the output is lower than on the other 3 NOR gates.

Let's start with my schematic.
[image]

And the strip-board layout:

[image]

I've also built a testing circuit which basically consists of a pair of buttons which connect A & B to 5V. There is no pull down resistor on this basic testing circuit, which I probably should have but I don't think this is particularly relevant since I expect all 4 of my NOR gates to behave the same as eachother.

The buttons and the output line also drive LEDs via transistors but again I don't think this is particularly relevant.

For the 3 good NOR gates, when I connect them but don't press any buttons the 2 A & B inputs are at about 0.1V, relative to ground, which seems fine to me.

For the bad NOR gate, when I connect it but don't press any buttons, A & B are both at more like 0.5-0.6V, which definitly seems wrong to me.

Furthermore, on the 3 good NOR gates the output is about 4.5V, while on the bad one it is only about 3.5V

I have checked the obvious things like bad solder joins and shorts between tracks.
I also swapped out the 2 transistors in case one of them had gone bad. I tested the new ones with a multimeter using [this method](https://knovhov.com/identify-the-pins-of-a-transistor/) (diode mode) before putting them in and they seem to be ok. The ones coming out also seem to be ok.

I imagine more information is required to make a full diagnosis but I don't know what else to check.

What am I missing?
Should I actually be concerned about this or is this kind of variation expected?

Just for completeness, although I doubt it's helpful - here is the completed circuit:

[image]
[image]

N.B. These 2N2222A331 transistors have their collector on the right when looking at the flat side.

Comment: (I remember burning three transistors in a row before suspecting the resistors. Turned out I had been sold 3k resistors as 1k which *looked* 1k (brown black red (gold) - guess what reminded me) - an off-colour orange…)

Comment: How did you establish the voltages? Do you feel at ease with non-driven inputs? I might try adding BE resistors, 1-10 k-ish.

Comment: (FWIW, I think the execution of the design rock solid.)

Comment: @greybeard what is BE? The resistors all came from the same line but I'll double check

Comment: The emitters are on ground so that would effectively be a pull down?

Comment: On both working and non-working the resistors are about 970 ohm, so we'll within gold tolerance

Comment: Yes, a resistor from Base to Emitter/GND to pull down the base of any open input.

Comment: I'll have to redo my testing circuit to ad the pull downs (which I need to do anyway, i made a right hash of it + I need to add a new feature for testing SR-latches which I didn't realise I couldn't do until I needed it! ) of course if I had done that I wouldn't have spotted this issue on the inputs only on the output (maybe?) do you think it's reasonable for the inputs to float that high? (in which I case I should probably stop worrying about it)

Comment: Thinking about it, I'd expect .5 V at an unconnected base of an NPN with the other end of the collector resistor at 5 V sooner than .1 - wait a sec… CircuitLab suggests on the order of .1 . I wouldn't consider leaving an input *real* floating "on my own devices", BJT or not.

Comment: Oh it won't be floating on the final assembly, only on the testing circuit. Collector is more like 4.7v (it's already been through my home made power controller (just a fancy on/off) and a lost a little bit in the process)

Comment: I'll re-work the tester and get back to you in a few days

Comment: Note that your gates will get interesting when connecting more than one input to any given output - I guess you have a fan-out of 2.5 - and a fan-in of about 6?! It may be useful to re-visit (LS) TTL input & output circuits.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware that fanout is going to be an issue, I had hoped to get more than 2 though. But I have designed a buffer for exactly this reason (and my clock will have 4 active high and 4 active low outputs for precisely this reason, although now you're making me wonder if that's enough) I'm not familiar with fan-in, I'll have to research that

Comment: @greybeard update: with my new testing circuit completed (with pull-down resistors), the A+B inputs are now at 0V on all 4 NOR gates, as you'd expect. However the output for one of them is still signficantly lower (2.3V) on one of them than the other 3 (4V)

Comment: Try to measure current from the output of the odd gate to ground. (Or may be the value of the "collector resistor" first.)